# Copy files then rename according to previous location into a new folder (batch)

Tags: shell, scripting

I’m running into a fairly simple problem but I have not been able to solve it. I have decided to look for some help. I’m not very good scripting and I was hoping I would find a Samaritan on this website.
I have files in the following format:

```
/test1/da/0/1/nnn.dat
/test1/da/0/2/nnn.dat
/test1/da/0/3/nnn.dat
…
/test1/da/y/n/nnn.dat
/test1/da/y+1/n+1/nnn.dat
/test1/da/y+1/n+2/nnn.dat
…
/test1/da/y+n/n+n/nnn.dat
```

I want to copy all nnn.dat files that are located in every subfolder into a /newfolder/nnn.dat in such a way that each nnn.dat gets renamed according to its location for example:

```
/newfolder/0_1_nnn.dat
/newfolder/0_2_nnn.dat
/newfolder/0_3_nnn.dat
…
/newfolder/y_n_nnn.dat
```

Also, I want to replace an specific line number of the nnn.dat file with an specific set of characters.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in /test/da/*/*/*.dat; do
  yn="${f##/test/da/}"
  b="${yn##*/}"
  yn="${y%/*}"
  y="${yn%%/*}"
  n="${yn##*/}
  cp "$f" "/newfolder/${y}_${n}_${b}"
done
```